# Sum of consecutive odd numbers

Tags: number-theory

Is there a general formula for the sum of consecutive odd numbers.  I don't mean from 1 to $n$ being $n^2$, I mean the way that the sum of one consecutive odd number is any odd number, 2 consecutive odd numbers are any even number 3 consecutive numbers are are any odd multiple of three, 4 consecutive odd numbers are any number which can be expressed as $8n$...
Is there a general pattern?

Comment: The sum of $a$ consecutive odd numbers is a difference of squares $(n + a)^2 - n^2 = a(a + 2n)$.

Comment: The sum of two consecutive odd numbers must be a multiple of $4$—not all even numbers are possible. The formula in Qiaochu Yuan's comment should allow you to characterize the values for any fixed $a$: any multiple of $2a$ if $a$ is even, any odd multiple of $a$ if $a$ is odd.

Comment: @Greg Martin  Do you know where I could find the proof for the sum of two consecutive odd numbers must be a multiple of 4?

Comment: $(2n-1)+(2n+1)=4n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. For, suppose you want counting from $k$ to $n$ (both odd numbers, included) consecutively. The sum of all numbers, even and odd, obviously is given by (please, see $S$ formula below)
$$S_{k,n}=(k+n)\frac{n-k+1}{2}.$$
But we need to eliminate all of the even numbers between $k$ and $n$, i.e. from $k+1$ to $n-1$. It is also obvious that the quantity of even numbers is one less that the quantity of odd ones, that is, $x+x-1=2x-1=n-k+1$. Thus, the number of odd and even numbers are, respectively
$$on_{k,n}=\frac{n-k+2}{2} \qquad\qquad en_{k,n}=\frac{n-k}{2}.$$
So that, you may apply the well-known formula $S=(a_1+a_n)n/2$ to get
$$S_{k,n}(on)=\frac{(n+k)(n-k+2)}{4}.$$
Notice that the following things.

-You can also calculate an arbitrary sequence of consecutive even numbers.

-If $k=1$, then $S_{1,n}(on)=((n+1)/2)^2.$